# Ajuda a fazer um select

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Ao fazer uma encomenda, devo salvar os dados dela (e do cliente) no banco de dados, certo? Mas ao fazer isso, **devo guardar também alguma informação do cliente na tabela de encomendas?** Visto que eu vou querer listar numa tela qual foi o cliente que fez certa encomenda.

Minhas tabelas:

```
tabela cliente 
-nome
-morada
-datanasc
-sexo
-pais
-cidade
-telemovel
-user
-senha

tabela encomenda
-id
-tamanho
-disponiblidade
-preco
```

Tenho que adicionar um campo na minha tabela `encomenda`, para que seja possível listar as encomendas de um `cliente`?

Comment: Na tabela de cliente vc deveria ter um `id_cliente` como chave primaria, e criar um campo novo em `encomendas` que é o `id_cliente` dessa como foreign key, assim vc pode ligar as duas tabelas.

Comment: Como faço a relação entre tabelas no mysql(xampp) ? sem ser pela linha de comandos

Answer (score 4):

Respondendo de forma curta, sim você precisa adicionar um identificador do cliente na sua tabela `encomenda`, esse identificador precisa ser uma `coluna` da tabela `cliente` que nunca irá se repetir. Nessa situação utilizamos as `chaves primárias` e normalmente com [`auto incremento`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Agora quer saber mais sobre o relacionamento entre as tabelas? Dê uma olhada neste excelente artigo do **[Thiago Belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/)**.

#### Conteúdo retirado do [blog do Thiago Belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql/).

### Relacionamento de Tabelas no MySQL

O relacionamento de tabelas é necessário quando temos mais de uma tabela com informações que podem e precisam ser cruzadas, por exemplo: categorias e produtos… Cada registro na tabela produtos estará ligado a um registro da tabela categorias.

Só pra vocês saberem, existem três níveis de relacionamento: nosso exemplo será um relação de `1:N` (fala-se “um pra N” ou “um para muitos”) onde cada categoria (1) contém um ou mais produtos (N)… Há também o `1:1` onde cada registro de uma tabela (1) está ligado a um e somente um registro de outra tabela (1)… E há outro nível de relacionamento, mais complexo, que é o `N:N` onde um ou mais registros de uma tabela (N) estão relacionados a um ou mais registros de outra tabela (N), que seria o exemplo de duas tabelas “produtos” e “tags” onde um produto tem várias tags e vários produtos pertencem a uma tag.

Não vou me aprofundar muito no assunto… Vou falar apenas da relação mais comum (1:N) e dar exemplos de como trabalhar com elas.

Para o nosso exemplo de hoje usaremos duas tabelas, chamadas “categorias” e “produtos”:

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `nome` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
 
CREATE TABLE `produtos` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `categoria_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `nome` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
  `preco` DECIMAL( 10,2 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

E vamos inserir alguns dados para exemplo:

```
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `categorias`
INSERT INTO `categorias` VALUES(1, 'Camisetas');
INSERT INTO `categorias` VALUES(2, 'Canecas');
 
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `produtos`
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES(1, 1, 'Camiseta Social', 15.00);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES(2, 1, 'Camiseta Regata', 11.99);
INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES(3, 2, 'Caneca Grande', 12.00);
```

Reparem que na tabela produtos temos uma coluna “especial”, que é a “categoria_id” (INT)… Ela é quem ajudará a fazer a relação das duas tabelas… Nessa coluna entrará o ID da categoria a qual o produto pertence… Ou seja: as duas camisetas pertencem a categoria “Camisetas” (ID 1) e o terceiro produto (a Caneca Grande) pertence a categoria “Canecas” (ID 2) e é na coluna “categoria_id” que armazenamos esses IDs que identificam as categorias.

Esse campo responsável pela relação é normalmente chamado de `foreing key (fk)` ou “chave estrangeira”.

### Mas qual a utilidade dessa tal “relação”?

Sem usar o relacionamento você poderia pegar todos os produtos e depois pegar as informações das categorias com uma segunda consulta, assim:

```
<?php
// Consulta que pega todos os produtos
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `produtos` ORDER BY `nome` ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($produto = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  // Aqui temos o array $produto com todos os valores do produto

  // Consulta para pegar os dados da categoria:
  $sqlC = "SELECT * FROM `categorias` WHERE `id` = " . $produto['categoria_id'];
  $queryC = mysql_query($sqlC);
  $categoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryC);

  echo 'Titulo: ' . $produto['nome'] . '';
  echo 'Preço: ' . $produto['preco'] . '';
  echo 'Categoria: ' . $categoria['nome']. '';
  echo '<hr />';
}
```

Até aí tudo bem… Não tem nenhum pecado nisso… Mas imagine que você tem uma loja com 1000 produtos (o que não é muito), seria executada 1 consulta para todos os produtos e, dentro do loop (while) seriam executadas outras 1000 consultas para pegar o nome da categoria a qual o produto pertence… Ou seja, 1001 consultas, o que é um absurdo.

### A mágica da relação

Agora vamos montar uma consulta que `DE UMA SÓ VEZ` irá pegar os dados de cada produto e também o nome da categoria… Com isso reduziremos nossas 1001 consultas pra… uma só! Sem mistérios, sem sub-consultas, nem consultas dentro do `while()`! :D

Mas antes de mostrar o script vou ajudar a vocês entenderem como a relação é feita… Antes a nossa consulta que pega apenas os produtos era assim:

```
SELECT * FROM `produtos` ORDER BY `nome` ASC
```

Sua tradução seria: *SELECIONAR todas as colunas da TABELA* `produtos` *ORDENADO PELO* `nome` *ASCENDETEMENTE*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora usaremos uma nova “palavra” do MySQL que é o JOIN (tradução: “unir”) e serve para unir resultados de duas tabelas.. ;)

Existem três tipos de JOIN mas não vou falar dos outros dois pois eles são MUITO pouco usados… Falaremos do `“INNER JOIN”` que exige que haja um registro que corresponda a relação nas duas tabelas, ou seja: se houver um produto sem categoria ou a categoria não existir na tabela categorias esse produto é omitido dos resultados.

A nossa consulta ficará assim:

```
SELECT `produtos`.* FROM `produtos`
  INNER JOIN `categorias` ON `produtos`.`categoria_id` = `categorias`.`id`
  ORDER BY `produtos`.`nome` ASC
```

Sua tradução seria: *SELECIONAR todas as colunas [da tabela produtos] da TABELA `produtos` UNINDO A TABELA `categorias` ONDE a coluna `categoria_id` [da tabela produtos] É IGUAL a coluna `id` [da tabela categorias] ORDENADO PELO `nome` [da tabela produtos] ASCENDETEMENTE*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A nossa “regra de relação” acontece ali entre o ON e o ORDER BY, dizemos que a relação entre as tabelas usará como referencia a coluna “categoria_id” da tabela “produtos” sendo igual a coluna “id” da tabela “categorias”… Se você fosse usar algum WHERE ele entraria depois do ON e antes do ORDER BY.

Pra quem ainda não entendeu, o ON é como o WHERE de uma consulta normal… É a regra da relação.

Repare que agora precisamos usar um formato diferente para identificar as colunas usando: `tabela`.`coluna`… Isso é necessário pois agora estamos trabalhando com duas tabelas.

Da forma que a nossa consulta está ainda não estamos pegando o nome da categoria… fazemos isso adicionando mais um campo na parte do SELECT, assim:

```
SELECT `produtos`.*, `categorias`.`nome` FROM `produtos`
  INNER JOIN `categorias` ON `produtos`.`categoria_id` = `categorias`.`id`
  ORDER BY `produtos`.`nome` ASC
```

Agora estamos pegando também o valor da coluna `"nome"` do registro encontrado (pela relação) na tabela `"categorias"`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que agora temos um novo problema… Nas duas tabelas existe uma coluna chamada “nome”, e quando estivermos lá no PHP, dentro do while, não teríamos como identificar de qual tabela pegamos as informações (veja a próxima imagem), pois as duas seriam `$produto['nome']`… Precisamos então renomear esse novo campo que adicionamos a busca, assim:

```
SELECT `produtos`.*, `categorias`.`nome` AS categoria FROM `produtos`
  INNER JOIN `categorias` ON `produtos`.`categoria_id` = `categorias`.`id`
  ORDER BY `produtos`.`nome` ASC
```

Agora o resultado de `categorias.nome` estará presente nos resultados como “categoria” e não “nome”… Sei que parece complicado de início mas vocês vão entender já já.

E por fim, faremos mais uma modificação, pra evitar ficar usando `tabela.coluna` também podemos renomear as tabelas, e com isso diminuir o tamanho da consulta:

```
SELECT p.*, c.`nome` AS categoria FROM `produtos` AS p
  INNER JOIN `categorias` AS c ON p.`categoria_id` = c.`id`
  ORDER BY p.`nome` ASC
```

Nesse caso `p` representará a tabela `“produtos”` e `c` representará a `“categorias”`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que parece uma consulta maior e mais complicada… Mas você fará o MySQL trabalhar muito menos se fizer assim, com JOINS, do que fazer uma 2ª consulta dentro do while… Essa é a forma mais correta de fazer consultas quando precisamos de informações vindas de mais de uma tabela.
Agora vamos ao nosso novo script de PHP que, sem dúvidas, é bem mais prático e eficiente:

```
<?php
// Consulta que pega todos os produtos e o nome da categoria de cada um
$sql = "SELECT p.*, c.`nome` AS categoria FROM `produtos` AS p INNER JOIN `categorias` AS c ON p.`categoria_id` = c.`id` ORDER BY p.`nome` ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($produto = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  // Aqui temos o array $produto com todos os dados encontrados
  echo 'Titulo: ' . $produto['nome'] . '';
  echo 'Preço: ' . $produto['preco'] . '';
  echo 'Categoria: ' . $produto['categoria']. '';
  echo '<hr />';
}
```

### Os outros tipos de JOINs

Existem também outros dois tipos de JOIN: o `LEFT JOIN` e o `RIGHT JOIN`:

Se usássemos o `LEFT JOIN` seriam retornados todos os produtos, independente se eles estão ligados a uma categoria (na tabela categorias) existente ou não.

Já o `RIGHT JOIN` seria exatamente o contrário: seriam retornados todos os produtos que pertencem categorias existentes e também o nome das outras categorias que não tem ligação com nenhum produto.

O uso desses outros tipos de JOIN é muito raro e acho que não vale a pena ficar filosofando sobre eles enquanto se aprende sobre relacionamentos.

### E a relação com mais de duas tabelas?

Só pra exemplo, essa seria a consulta que pega os produtos, as categorias e o nome do usuário que cadastrou o produto e filtrando apenas pelos produtos ativos:

```
SELECT p.*, c.`nome` AS categoria, u.`nome` AS usuario FROM `produtos` AS p
  INNER JOIN `categorias` AS c ON p.`categoria_id` = c.`id`
  INNER JOIN `usuarios` AS u ON p.`usuario_id` = u.`id`
  WHERE (p.`ativo` = 1) ORDER BY p.`nome` ASC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Fonte: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

No seu caso temos um relacionamento N para N entre as tabelas. O ideal seria criar uma tabela intermediária que faria a amarração entre as duas, a qual conteria as chaves primárias das linhas relacionadas. É o que normalmente se faz quando temos este tipo de situação.

Um exemplo:

```
    CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(

        ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        NOME VARCHAR(30),
        CONSTRAINT CNS_PK_CLIENTE PRIMARY KEY(ID)

    );

    CREATE TABLE COMPRA(

        ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        VALOR DOUBLE(8,2),
        CONSTRAINT CNS_PK_COMPRA PRIMARY KEY(ID)

    );

    CREATE TABLE CLIENTE_COMPRA(

        DATA_COMPRA DATETIME NOT NULL,
        ID_CLIENTE INT,
        ID_COMPRA INT,
        CONSTRAINT CNS_FK_CLIENTE FOREIGN KEY(ID_CLIENTE) REFERENCES CLIENTE(ID),
        CONSTRAINT CNS_FK_COMPRA FOREIGN KEY(ID_COMPRA) REFERENCES COMPRA(ID),
        CONSTRAINT CNS_PK_CLIENTE_COMPRA PRIMARY KEY(ID_CLIENTE, ID_COMPRA)

    );
```